# is there a way to catch keyboard inputs before they are send to the interface in windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, emacs

I am an Emacs keystrokes lover, I think they are just great and everytime I have a chance to actually change the default keystrokes of my favorite IDEs to `emacs` I do so.

But one thing that makes me sad about windows is the obviously impossibility of changing the default system keystrokes. And I understand perfectly, that would be a mess to provide such a feature.

What I mean is binding a new keystroke to invoke an original windows keystroke.

For instance, if I `ctrl+n` on my keyboard, I want to prevent the default windows behavior to be triggered (if any are attached to that keystroke) and instead trigger another behavior (in that case arrow-down).

I believe the only way to do this is on a low-level development program (such as c or c++) and using the *winapi*.

What's your opinion on how I could achieve that ?

Comment: Use [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/)

Comment: @DavidPostill very fast, simple, easy. I already made my emacs keystrokes that I'm using right now in this text area to sometimes easily edit the text back without touching my mouse and hurting my arm and shoulder and back muscles. thanks a lot David.